# jQuery submits the wrong html form

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a php script that fetches items from database and allows users to vote for them, I give each one of those fetched items a (html form) with one (input text field) and a (submit button) to submit an entered score when clicked, and I have a jQuery script in the very same page that inserts the score via that form to the database without refreshing the page, everything seems to be working just fine except the script has one.

This script allows only the very first (html form) in the loop to submit and this first (html form) affects item that does not follow it in the loop, how to make every form attributed to its item?

Alongside this I also want the script to return a notification for the user who submits the score to inform them whether the data is successfully inserted or failed and when success I want to the score that the user submitted to appear for them after the submission

Any help is appreciated, here is my code:

```
<body>

  <div id="items-wrapper">
    <?php //function where i fetch items/records from database $items=g et_items_function($page_id); if(!$items){ echo 'There are no items in this page yet!'; }else{ ?>
    <div id="item">
      <?php //looping the fetched items/records foreach($items as $item){ $_itemid=$ item[ 'item_id']; $_name=$ item[ 'item_name']; $item_file='path/to/items/name-' .$_name. '-id-'.$_itemid. '.jpg'; ?>
      <ul id="responds">
        <!--i want to append data here-->
      </ul>

      <img src="<?php echo $item_file; ?>" />

      <form action="setItemScore.php?itemPass=<?php echo $_itemid.'&pagePass='.$_pageid; ?>" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="content_txt" id="contentText" placeholder="Enter score" />
        <button id="FormSubmit">Add Score</button>

        <img src="images/loading.gif" id="LoadingImage" style="display:none" />
      </form>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      //Ajax request to setItemScore.php
      $("#FormSubmit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($("#contentText").val() === '') {
          alert("Please enter some text!");
          return false;
        }

        $("#FormSubmit").hide();
        $("#LoadingImage").show();

        var myData = 'score_value=' + $("#contentText").val();
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "setItemScore.php?itemPass=<?php echo $_itemid.'&pagePass='.$_pageid; ?>",
          dataType: "text",
          data: myData,
          success: function(response) {
            $("#responds").append(response);
            $("#contentText").val('');
            $("#FormSubmit").show();
            $("#LoadingImage").hide();

          },
          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $("#FormSubmit").show();
            $("#LoadingImage").hide();
            alert(thrownError);
          }
        });
      });

    });
  </script>

</body>
```

Comment: 2 things :  
- be sure your Id is unique
- button html by default is "type=submit" so put "type=button"

Comment: The id i pass via form action is unique for sure!!

Comment: Id must be unique in page, use the class if an element must be present multiple times. SO change id="FormSubmit" by class="FormSubmit" and change your listener

Comment: Good point, but still the problem exists!

Answer (score 1):

**Issue #1**

You should always use the `.submit()` method when a form is being submitted rather than the submit button `onclick()` for two reasons. 1) When using `inputs` you can hit enter and submit the form bypassing the entire method. 2) `.submit()` uses the form allowing you to get children items for that form.

With that in mind I would add a class name to the forms that you know are being submitted through ajax like:

```
<form class="ajax-form" action="setItemScore.php?itemPass=<?php echo $_itemid.'&pagePass='.$_pageid; ?>" method="POST">
...
</form>
```

Then instead of using `.onclick()` you can use:

```
$('.ajax-form').submit(function(e){
...
});
```

**Issue #2**

In your AJAX request you are using the following line:

`url: "setItemScore.php?itemPass=<?php echo $_itemid.'&pagePass='.$_pageid; ?>",`

This is always going to set `$_itemid` to the last iteration from your above `foreach()` loop instead of the `action` from the form.

If you use the method mentioned above in issue #1 then you could simply use the forms action property:

`url: $(this).prop('action')`

Whereas `$(this)` is the form.

Comment: You're right, the script affects the last from in the loop, could you give me a live example on fiddle?

Comment: If you look at the bottom you should just be able to use the forms action value

Comment: I used the property url: $(this).prop('action') instead of my code line but nothing happened!

Comment: did you adapt your code to the whole solution i provided. changing just that line will not fix your problem

Comment: I gave the form a class called ajax-form and then replaced $(".FormSubmit").click(function (e) { with $('.ajax-form').submit(function(e){, after that i used this code line url: $(this).prop('action')..